# Can I pass a parameter to the first command in a multipart npm script?

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to have an npm task that looks something like

`"deploy": "npm version; echo \"Do other stuff\""`

But I need to get the version argument to npm version for it to do anything. Is that possible?

The only thing I have working now is to move the following commands into a `postdeploy` task, which then works if I run `$ npm run deploy minor`, but I want to know if what I describe above is possible.

Comment: Are you looking to pass the `npm -v` result to the next command?

Comment: that wouldn't be necessary, but it would be valuable to know if it's possible